# Error using utf-8 filenames in python script

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

I have a seemingly impossible conundrum and hope that you guys can help point me in the right direction. I have been coming to and leaving this project for weeks now and I think it is about time that I solve it, with your help hopefully.

I am making a script which is supposed to read a bunch of .xls excel files from a directory structure, parse their contents and load it into a mysql database. Now, in the main function, a list of (croatian) file names gets passed to the xlrd, and that is where the problem lies.

The environment is up to date FreeBSD 9.1.

I get the following error when executing the script:

```
mars:~/20130829> python megascript.py

Python version: 2.7.5

Filesstem encoding is: UTF-8
Removing error.log if it exists...
It doesn't.
Done!
Connecting to database...
Done!
MySQL database version: 5.6.13
Loading pilots...
Done!
Loading tehnicians...
Done!
Loading aircraft registrations...
Done!
Loading file list...
Done!
Processing files...
/2006/1_siječanj.xls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "megascript.py", line 540, in <module>
    main()
  File "megascript.py", line 491, in main
    data = readxlsfile(files, 'UPIS', piloti, tehnicari, helikopteri)
  File "megascript.py", line 129, in readxlsfile
    workbook = open_workbook(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/xlrd/__init__.py",     line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/2006/1_sije\u010danj.xls'
```

I have included the complete output to make the code fow easier to follow.
I suppose that the problem is in xlrd not accepting utf-8 file list. I'm not sure how to get around that without messing around with xlrd code though. Any ideas?

Here goes the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env/python
# -#*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, getopt, codecs, csv, MySQLdb, platform
from mmap import mmap,ACCESS_READ
from xlrd import open_workbook, xldate_as_tuple

# Define constants

NALET_OUT = ''
PUTNICI_OUT = ''
DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USER = 'user'
DB_PASS = 'pass'
DB_DATABASE = 'eth'
START_DIR = u'./'
ERROR_FILE = START_DIR + 'mega_error.log'

# Functions    
def isNumber(s):
# Check if a string could be a number
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def getMonth(f):
# Izvuci mjesec iz imena datoteke u formatu "1_sijecanj.xls"

    temp = os.path.basename(f)
    temp = temp.split('_')
    mjesec = int(temp[0])
    return mjesec

def getYear(f):
# Izvuci godinu iz path
    f = f.split('/')
    godina = f[-2]
    return godina

def databaseVersion(cur):
# Print Mysql database version
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
        result = cur.fetchone()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        try:
            print "MySQL Error [%d]: %s]" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        except IndexError:
            print "MySQL  Error: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

    print "MySQL database version: %s" % result

def getQuery(cur, sql_query):
# Perform passed query on passed database
    try:
        cur.execute(sql_query)
        result = cur.fetchall()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        try:
            print "MySQL Error [%d]: %s]" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        except IndexError:
            print "MySQL  Error: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    return result

def getFiles():

    files = []

    # Find subdirectories
    for i in [x[0] for x in os.walk(START_DIR)]:

        if (i != '.' and isNumber(os.path.basename(i))):

            # Find files in subdirectories
            for j in [y[2] for y in os.walk(i)]:

                # For every file in file list
                for y in j:
                    fn, fe = os.path.splitext(y)
                    is_mj = fn.split("_")
                    if(fe == '.xls' and y.find('_') and isNumber(is_mj[0])):
                        mj = fn.split('_')
                        files.append(i.lstrip('.') + "/" + y)

    # Sort list cronologically
    files.sort(key=lambda x: getMonth(x))
    files.sort(key=lambda x: getYear(x))

    return files

def errhandle(f, datum, var, vrijednost, ispravka = "NULL"):
# Get error information, print it on screen and write to error.log

    f = unicode(str(f), 'utf-8')
    datum = unicode(str(datum), 'utf-8')
    var = unicode(str(var), 'utf-8')
    try:
        vrijednost = unicode(str(vrijednost.decode('utf-8')), 'utf-8')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        vrijednost = vrijednost
    ispravka = unicode(str(ispravka), 'utf-8')

    err_f = codecs.open(ERROR_FILE, 'a+', 'utf-8')
    line = f + ": " + datum + " " + var + "='" + vrijednost\
                    + "' Ispravka='" + ispravka + "'"

    #print "%s" % line

    err_f.write(line)
    err_f.close()

def readxlsfile(files, sheet, piloti, tehnicari, helikopteri):
# Read xls file and return a list of rows

    data = []
    nalet = []
    putn = []
    id_index = 0

    # For every file in list
    for f in files:
        print "%s" % f
        temp = f.split('/')
        godina = str(temp[-2])
        temp = os.path.basename(f).split('_')
        mjesec = str(temp[0])

        workbook = open_workbook(f)
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('UPIS')

        # For every row that doesn't contain '' or 'POSADA' or 'dan' etc...
        for ri in range(sheet.nrows):
            if sheet.cell(ri,1).value!=''\
               and sheet.cell(ri,2).value!='POSADA'\
               and sheet.cell(ri,1).value!='dan'\
               and (sheet.cell(ri,2).value!=''):

                temp = sheet.cell(ri, 1).value
                temp = temp.split('.')
                dan = temp[0]

                # Datum
                datum = "'" + godina + "-" + mjesec + "-" + dan + "'"

                # Kapetan
                kapetan = ''
                kapi=''
                if sheet.cell(ri, 2).value == "":
                    kapetan = "NULL"
                else:
                    kapetan = sheet.cell(ri, 2).value
                    if kapetan[-1:] == " ":
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'kapetan', kapetan, kapetan[-1:])
                        kapetan = kapetan[:-1]
                    if(kapetan):
                        try:
                            kapi = [x[0] for x in piloti if x[2].lower() == kapetan]
                            kapi = kapi[0]
                        except ValueError:
                            errhandle(f, datum, 'kapetan', kapetan, '')
                            kapetan = ''
                        except IndexError:
                            errhandle(f, datum, 'kapetan', kapetan, '')
                            kapi = 'NULL'
                    else:
                        kapi="NULL"

                # Kopilot
                kopilot = ''
                kopi = ''
                if sheet.cell(ri, 3).value == "":
                    kopi = "NULL"
                else:
                    kopilot = sheet.cell(ri, 3).value
                    if kopilot[-1:] == " ":
                        errhandle(f, datum,'kopilot', kopilot,\
                                  kopilot[:-1])
                    if(kopilot):
                        try:
                            kopi = [x[0] for x in piloti if x[2].lower() == kopilot]
                            kopi = kopi[0]
                        except ValueError:
                            errhandle(f, datum,'kopilot', kopilot, '')
                        except IndexError:
                            errhandle(f, datum, 'kopilot', kopilot, '')
                            kopi = 'NULL'
                    else:
                        kopi="NULL"

                # Teh 1
                teh1 = ''
                t1i = ''
                if sheet.cell(ri, 4).value=='':
                    t1i = 'NULL'
                else:
                    teh1 = sheet.cell(ri, 4).value
                    if teh1[-1:] == " ":
                        errhandle(f, datum,'teh1', teh1, teh1[:-1])
                        teh1 = 'NULL'
                    if(teh1):
                        try:
                            t1i = [x[0] for x in tehnicari if x[2].lower() == teh1]
                            t1i = t1i[0]
                        except ValueError:
                            errhandle(f, datum,'teh1', teh1, '')
                        except IndexError:
                            errhandle(f, datum, 'teh1', teh1, '')
                            t1i = 'NULL'
                        else:
                            t1i="NULL"

                # Teh 2
                teh2=''
                t2i=''
                if sheet.cell(ri, 5).value=='':
                    t2i = "NULL"
                else:
                    teh2 = sheet.cell(ri, 5).value
                    if teh2[-1:] == " ":
                        errhandle(f, datum,'teh2', teh2, teh2[-1:])
                        teh2 = ''
                    if(teh2):
                        try:
                            t2i = [x[0] for x in tehnicari if x[2].lower() == teh2]
                            t2i = t2i[0]
                        except ValueError:
                            errhandle(f, datum,'teh2', teh2, 'NULL')
                            t2i = 'NULL'
                        except IndexError:
                            errhandle(f, datum,'teh2', teh2, 'NULL')
                            t2i = 'NULL'
                    else:
                        t2i="NULL"

                # Oznaka
                oznaka = ''
                heli = ''
                if sheet.cell(ri, 6).value=="":
                    oznaka = errhandle(f, datum, "helikopter", oznaka, "")
                else:
                    oznaka = str(int(sheet.cell(ri, 6).value))
                    try:
                        heli = [x[0] for x in helikopteri if x[0] == oznaka]
                    except ValueError:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'helikopter', oznaka, '')
                    except IndexError:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'helikopter', oznaka, '')
                        heli = ''

                # Uvjeti
                uvjeti = sheet.cell(ri, 9).value

                # Letova
                letova_dan = 0
                letova_noc = 0
                letova_ifr = 0
                letova_sim = 0
                if sheet.cell(ri, 7).value == "":
                    errhandle(f, datum, 'letova', letova, '')
                else:
                    letova = str(int(sheet.cell(ri, 7).value))

                if uvjeti=="vfr":
                    letova_dan = letova
                elif uvjeti=="ifr":
                    letova_ifr = letova
                elif uvjeti=="sim":
                    letova_sim = letova
                else:
                    letova_noc = letova

                #Block time
                bt_dan = "'00:00:00'"
                bt_noc = "'00:00:00'"
                bt_ifr = "'00:00:00'"
                bt_sim = "'00:00:00'"
                try:
                    bt_tpl = xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell(ri, 8).value, workbook.datemode)
                    bt_m = bt_tpl[4]
                    bt_h = bt_tpl[3]
                    bt = "'" + str(bt_h).zfill(2)+":"+str(bt_m)+":00'"
                except ValueError or IndexError:
                    errhandle(f, datum, 'bt', sheet.cell(ri,8).value, '')
                if uvjeti[:3]=="vfr":
                    bt_dan = bt
                elif uvjeti[:3]=="ifr":
                    bt_ifr = bt
                elif uvjeti[:3]=="sim":
                    bt_sim = bt
                elif uvjeti[:2] == "no":
                    bt_noc = bt
                else:
                    errhandle(f, datum, 'uvjeti', uvjeti, '')

                # Vrsta leta
                vrsta = "'" + sheet.cell(ri, 10).value + "'"

                # Vjezba
                vjezba = 'NULL';
                try:
                    vjezba = sheet.cell(ri, 11).value
                    if vjezba == '':
                        # Too many results
                        #errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', vjezba, '')
                        vjezba = 'NULL'
                    if vjezba == "?":
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), '')
                        vjezba = 'NULL'
                    if str(vjezba) == 'i':
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), '')
                        vjezba = 'NULL'
                    if str(vjezba)[-1:] == 'i':
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba),\
                        str(vjezba).rstrip('i'))
                        vjezba = str(vjezba).rstrip('i')
                    if str(vjezba).find(' i ') != -1:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split(' i ')[0])
                        vjezba = str(vjezba).split(' i ')
                        vjezba = vjezba[0]
                    if str(vjezba)[-1:] == 'm':
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).rstrip('m'))
                        vjezba = str(vjezba).rstrip('m')
                    if str(vjezba).find(';') != -1:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split(';')[0])
                        temp = str(vjezba).split(';')
                        vjezba = temp[0]
                    if str(vjezba).find('/') != -1:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split('/')[0])
                        temp = str(vjezba).split('/')
                        vjezba = temp[0]
                    if str(vjezba).find('-') != -1:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split('-')[0])
                        temp = str(vjezba).split('-')
                        vjezba = temp[0]
                    if str(vjezba).find(',') != -1:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split(',')[0])
                        temp = str(vjezba).split(',')
                        vjezba = temp[0]
                    if str(vjezba).find('_') != -1:
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split('_')[0])
                        temp = str(vjezba).split('_')
                        vjezba = temp[0]
                    if str(vjezba) == 'bo':
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), '')
                        vjezba = 'NULL'
                    if str(vjezba).find(' ') != -1:
                        if str(vjezba) == 'pp 300':
                            errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split(' ')[1])
                            temp = str(vjezba).split(' ')
                            vjezba = temp[1]
                        else:
                            errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), str(vjezba).split(' ')[0])
                            temp = str(vjezba).split(' ')
                            vjezba = temp[0]
                    if str(vjezba) == 'pp':
                        errhandle(f, datum, 'vjezba', str(vjezba), '')
                        vjezba = ''
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    errhandle(f, datum, 'Unicode error! vjezba', vjezba, '')

                if vjezba != 'NULL':
                    vjezba = int(float(vjezba))

                # Visinska slijetanja

                # Putnici
                vp1 = str(sheet.cell(ri, 12).value)
                bp1 = str(sheet.cell(ri, 13).value)
                vp2 = str(sheet.cell(ri, 14).value)
                bp2 = str(sheet.cell(ri, 15).value)

                # Teret
                teret = ''
                teret = str(sheet.cell(ri, 16).value)
                if teret == '':
                    teret = 0

                # Baja
                baja = ''
                if sheet.cell(ri, 17).value == '':
                    baja = 0
                else:
                    baja = int(sheet.cell(ri, 17).value) / 2 # dodano /2 da se dobiju tone  

# Redosljed csv
                id_index = id_index + 1

                row = [id_index, datum, kapi, kopi, t1i, t2i, oznaka,\
                       letova, letova_dan, letova_noc, letova_ifr,\
                       letova_sim, bt, bt_dan, bt_noc, bt_ifr,\
                       bt_sim, vrsta, vjezba, teret, baja]

                row = [str(i) for i in row]
                nalet.append(row)

                putn = []
                if bp1 != '':
                    put = [id_index, vp1, bp1]
                    putn.append(put)
                if bp2 != '':
                    put = [id_index, vp2, bp2]
                    putn.append(put)

    data.append(nalet)
    data.append(putn)
    return data

def main():

    # Python version
    print "\nPython version: %s \n" % platform.python_version()

    # Print filesystem encoding
    print "Filesstem encoding is: %s" % sys.getfilesystemencoding()

    # Remove error file if exists
    print "Removing error.log if it exists..."
    try:
        os.remove(ERROR_FILE)
        print "It did."
    except OSError:
        print "It doesn't."
        pass
    print "Done!"

    # Connect to database
    print "Connecting to database..."
    db = MySQLdb.connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE,\
                         use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
    cur=db.cursor()
    print "Done!"

    # Database version

    databaseVersion(cur)

    # Load pilots, tehnicians and helicopters from db

    print "Loading pilots..."
    sql_query = "SELECT eth_osobnici.id, eth_osobnici.ime,\
    eth_osobnici.prezime FROM eth_osobnici RIGHT JOIN \
    eth_letacka_osposobljenja ON eth_osobnici.id=\
    eth_letacka_osposobljenja.id_osobnik WHERE \
    eth_letacka_osposobljenja.vrsta_osposobljenja='kapetan' \
    OR eth_letacka_osposobljenja.vrsta_osposobljenja='kopilot'"

    #piloti = []
    #piloti = getQuery(cur, sql_query)


    piloti=[]
    temp = []
    temp = getQuery(cur, sql_query)
    for row in temp:
        piloti.append(row)
    print "Done!"

    print "Loading tehnicians..."
    sql_query = "SELECT eth_osobnici.id, eth_osobnici.ime,\
    eth_osobnici.prezime FROM eth_osobnici RIGHT JOIN \
    eth_letacka_osposobljenja ON eth_osobnici.id=\
    eth_letacka_osposobljenja.id_osobnik WHERE \
    eth_letacka_osposobljenja.vrsta_osposobljenja='tehničar 1' \
    OR eth_letacka_osposobljenja.vrsta_osposobljenja='tehničar 2'"

    tehnicari=[]
    temp = []
    temp = getQuery(cur, sql_query)
    for row in temp:
        tehnicari.append(row)
    print "Done!"

    print "Loading aircraft registrations..."
    sql_query = "SELECT id FROM eth_helikopteri"

    helikopteri=[]
    temp = []
    temp = getQuery(cur, sql_query)
    for row in temp:
        helikopteri.append(row)
    print "Done!"

    # Get file names to process
    print "Loading file list..."
    files = getFiles()
    print "Done!"

    # Process all files from array
    print "Processing files..."
    data = readxlsfile(files, 'UPIS', piloti, tehnicari, helikopteri)
    print "Done!"

    # Enter new information in database
    result = 0

    print "Reseting database..."
    sql_query = "DELETE FROM eth_nalet"
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    db.commit()
    sql_query = "ALTER TABLE eth_nalet AUTO_INCREMENT=0"
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    db.commit()
    print "Done!"

    print "Loading data in 'eth_nalet'..."

    for row in data[0]:
        sql_query = """INSERT INTO eth_nalet (id, datum, kapetan, 
        kopilot, teh1, teh2, registracija, letova_uk, letova_dan, 
        letova_noc, letova_ifr, letova_sim, block_time, block_time_dan, 
        block_time_noc, block_time_ifr, block_time_sim, vrsta_leta,
        vjezba, teret, baja) VALUES (%s)""" % (", ".join(row))

        cur.execute(sql_query)
        db.commit()

    print "Done!"

    print "Loading data in 'eth_putnici'..."

    for row in data[1]:
        sql_query = """INSERT INTO eth_putnici (id_leta,
        vrsta_putnika, broj_putnika) VALUES (%s)""" % (", ".join(row))

        cur.execute(sql_query)
        db.commit()

    print "Done!"

    # Close the database connection
    print "Closing database connection..."
    if cur:
        cur.close()
    if db:
        db.close()
    print "Database closed!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I apologize for not translating comments in the code, it was an old project of mine and I tend to make comments in english now. If something needs explanation please fire away.

The funny thing is that if I print the file list to the screen, they display just fine. But when they get passed to the xlrd they don't seem to be in the right format.

Respectfully,
me

Comment: Do you get the same error with: ```for f in getFiles(): with open(f, 'rb') as f: pass``` ?

Comment: You mean try and pass a file handle to the program? I think that xlrd takes only a file name as argument so I don't think that would do the trick. Besides, It would require me to rewrite most of the readxlsfile function. Nice suggestion but I think I will save it for last resort. I am hoping there is a simpler fix, there has to be some way to fix the encoding.

Comment: I looked in the xlrd files to see if there was a clue.  It just uses the open() function on the string you pass it.  So I was wondering if you get an exception/error with a short script that just iterates over your file paths and tries to open them.

Comment: I misunderstood you, I apologize. A very good point. It fails with the same error as in the xlrd.  
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/2006/1_sije\u010danj.xls'

Comment: Maybe it would be relevant to say that when I do print "%s" % files[0] it outputs to the screen correctly with no errors. It seems that the only time when the error occurs is when I try to open the same files[n] with open(f, 'rb'). Look at this:          >>> open ("1_siječanj.xls", 'rb')
<open file '1_sije\xc4\x8danj.xls', mode 'rb' at 0x801c56270>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to find an error! It wasn't due to encoding error after all. It was a logic error.

In function getFiles() I stripped the leading "." from file list, and didn't strip "./" as I ought to. So, naturally file names were "/2006/1_siječanj.xls" instead of "2006/1_siječanj.xls" as they should be. It was an IOError and not not UnicodeEncodeError. And result of my oversight was that the script tried to find an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Well this was embarrassing. Thank you guys, hope this post helps someone else pay more attention to the error types python throws at us.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like xlrd isn't converting the Unicode type to a local encoded type before trying to open the file. Python has guessed that the filesystem name encoding is UTF-8 and has correctly converted the č to the correct Unicode point.

There's two ways to fix this:

1. Try encoding the Unicode filename before asking xlrd to open it with:

   ```
   workbook = open_workbook(f.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding() ) )
   ```
2. Use raw 8bit filenames and don't convert filenames to Unicode

   ```
   START_DIR = './'
   ```

IMHO, option 2 is probably safer in-case filenames haven't been written with UTF-8 filenames.

**UPD**

Note, os.walk returns Unicode strings when the given path is a Unicode string. A normal string path will return binary strings. This is the same behaviour as os.listdir (http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Example:

```
$ ls
€.txt
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir(".")
['\xe2\x82\xac.txt']
>>> os.listdir(u".")
[u'\u20ac.txt']
```

(e282 = UTF-8 €)

**Remember**: In Unix, unlike Windows, filenames do not contain encoding hints. Filenames are simply 8bit strings. You need to know what encoding they were created with if you want to convert them to a different encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Well, option 2 did not work. result was:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/2006/1_sije\u010danj.xls'
Option no 2 produced following error:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/2006/1_sije\xc4\x8danj.xls'

Errors are obviously different. It does seem like something gets encoded twice. I don't know how to resolve it though.

Comment: Does the script work if the filenames are pure ASCII?

Comment: The environment variables are set to uft-8. That would make os.walk return the UTF-8 encoded file names would it not? So I would have to convert them manually to ASCII in script with str(). If correct, I tried it and id didn't work. Still returns the same error.

Comment: It's not well documented, but os.walk returns Unicode types if the path given is a Unicode type. Otherwise the result is a binary string. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir for more info. Try renaming your files to pure ASCII to check if it's a encoding problem or perhaps a path typo or ACL

Comment: It was a path typo. IOError. I totally overlooked the error type. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.